# What is a good way to declare math operators?

Tags: math-operators

it's not really clear to me how to declare unary and binary math operators in a "good" way. At the very least, I'd like spacing to be correct. But I'd also like the defined macro to be used "as is" in text mode (with correct spacing here also).

For instance, I have operators called X and U, the former being unary while the latter is binary. As I want them to work both in math and text mode, with correct spacing, I define them the following way, as of now:

```
\newcommand{\U}{\ensuremath{\mathbin{\mathbf{U}}}\xspace}
\newcommand{\X}{\ensuremath{{\mathbf{X}}\xspace}
```

But I'm not really sure it's the best practice...

Comment: `\DeclareMathOperator`

Comment: I see no reason for wanting the commands to work in text mode.

Comment: I agree with egreg here, you really should not mix text and math. Using `$\U$` gives a really good semantic separation between what is suppose to be interpreted as text and what should be interpreted as math.

Comment: @egreg @daleif Well, for instance, there are some cases where something is both an abbreviation and the name of a mathematical object. E.g. I could write `\fol is first-order logic` as well as `$\phi \in \fol$`, with `\fol` printed as `FOL`.

Comment: @Grayswandyr I see no reason for not using `$\fol$ is first-order logic`.

Comment: @egreg laziness? :-) Anyway, it's indeed not the most important aspect. The hardest thing is that I don't find very clear what is the preferred way to define unary and binary operators.

Comment: `$\mathbin{-}c = a \mathbin{-} b$` produces the proper unary/binary behavior (i.e., the same as `$-c = a - b$`.  Thus, proper spacing achieved with `\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\X{\mathbin{\mathbf{X}}}
\begin{document}
$\X c = a \X b$
\end{document}`